# How to in React Component constructor set this state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constructor

I still learn much React JavaScript and now I can't understand how to create this initial state.

In the `constructor` here in the code I want to add to `state` by running this line:

```
    this.state = CsvViewer.parse(props.data);
```

And direct after I want to add more `state` variables like this:

```
    this.state = {
        filters: {},
        sortColumn: null,
        sortDirection: null,
    };
```

The problem now is that `state` does not contain the first call to `CsvViewer`. How can I add to state both the call to `CsvViewer` and the other state variables?

Code:

```
    class CsvViewer extends Component {
        static parse(data) {
            const rows = [];
            const columns = [];
    
            new CSV(data).forEach(array => {
                if (columns.length < 1) {
                    array.forEach((cell, idx) => {
                        columns.push({
                            key: `key-${idx}`,
                            name: cell,
                            resizable: true,
                            sortable: true,
                            filterable: true,
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    const row = {};
                    array.forEach((cell, idx) => {
                        row[`key-${idx}`] = cell;
                    });
                    rows.push(row);
                }
            });
            return { rows, columns };
        }
    
        constructor(props) {
            super();
            this.state = CsvViewer.parse(props.data);
            this.state = {
                filters: {},
                sortColumn: null,
                sortDirection: null,
            };
        }


    UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        // TODO
        this.setState(CsvViewer.parse(nextProps.data));
    }

    handleGridSort = (sortColumn, sortDirection) => {
        // this.setState({ sortColumn, sortDirection });
    };

    render() {
        const { rows, columns } = this.state;
        const { height } = this.props;
        return (
            <ReactDataGrid
                enableCellAutoFocus={false}
                columns={columns}
                rowsCount={rows ? rows.length: 0}
                rowGetter={i => rows[i]}
                minHeight={height || 650}
                onGridSort={this.handleGridSort}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default CsvViewer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few options for adding properties to an object. Here's the one i would usually do, using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals). It will create a shallow copy of the object returned by parse, and add in the extra properties you define:

```
this.state = {
  ...CsvViewer.parse(props.data),
  filters: {},
  sortColumn: null,
  sortDirection: null,
}
```

[Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) can be used to do something similar:

```
this.state = Object.assign({}, CsvViewer.parse(props.data), {
  filters: {},
  sortColumn: null,
  sortDirection: null,
});
```

Or you could just add the individual properties one at a time:

```
this.state = CsvViewer.parse(props.data);
this.state.filters = {};
this.state.sortColumn = null;
this.state.sortDirection = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set csvViewer, filters, sortColumn, and sortDirection under one state like so.

```
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
            csvViewer: CsvViewer.parse(props.data),
            filters: {},
            sortColumn: null,
            sortDirection: null,
        };
    }
```

The second this.state will overwrite your first this.state, you can have everything under one state.